# How to find a file automatically without actually knowing the full path file in directory in C# windows application Form

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0

I need help with my c# application, my application is basicly done just need a minor tweak and should be done.

My program does many functionalities. but the one I need help is the following:

My program will let the user first create a excel file, there I have three buttons first button is open that will open the created file created by the user and the user will save the file in any location, but when the button open needs to find that file to where the user saved the file. right now button will work if I manually put the location of specific location of the file. but my application will be use it many users. and each user will save their own file in any directory location. I also have a button that will save data to the excel file and also to close it but those work fine as long the open file works.

this part of the code will create and save to a user location of desired. then the open button function need to automatically find the just recent file created from the computer directory. as I said before if I put the specific location the open button works but i don't want to put a specific location of the file because the user will choose that location of the excel file.

```
    private void tlpMenuItem_SaveAs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string sd;
        svFileDialog_SaveButton.ShowDialog();
        //saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:";
        svFileDialog_SaveButton.Filter = "Excel File|*.xlsx|All Files|*.*";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        ExcelApp.Columns.ColumnWidth = 20;
        sd = svFileDialog_SaveButton.FileName;
        ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(sd + ".xlsx");
        ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
        ExcelApp.Quit();
        MessageBox.Show("Excel file created");

    }
    private void OpenFile()
    {

        string findFile = "";
        xlexcel = new Excel.Application();

        xlexcel.Visible = true;

        // Open a File
        xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyFile.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Username";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Password";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Warehouse Location";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Date";
    }
```

Here is my full code of the created file, open, save data and close excel file

```
    private void tlpMenuItem_SaveAs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string sd;
        svFileDialog_SaveButton.ShowDialog();
        //saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:";
        svFileDialog_SaveButton.Filter = "Excel File|*.xlsx|All Files|*.*";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        ExcelApp.Columns.ColumnWidth = 20;
        sd = svFileDialog_SaveButton.FileName;
        ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(sd + ".xlsx");
        ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
        ExcelApp.Quit();
        MessageBox.Show("Excel file created");

    }
    private void OpenFile()
    {

        string findFile = "";
        xlexcel = new Excel.Application();

        xlexcel.Visible = true;

        // Open a File
        xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyFile.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Username";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Password";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Warehouse Location";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Date";
    }
    private void SaveDataToAFile()
    {
        int _lastRow = xlWorkSheet.Range["A" + xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlUp].Row + 1;

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 1] = txt_Username.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 2] = txt_Password.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 3] = cmb_DatabaseSelection.SelectedIndex.ToString();
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 4] = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private void CloseFile()
    {
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlexcel.Quit();

        ReleaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        ReleaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        ReleaseObject(xlexcel);
    }

    private void ReleaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: not understand your question.

Comment: It kind of sounds like you want to prompt the user to select a file with  [`OpenFileDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`SaveFileDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx), is that correct?

Comment: Hmmm...  I'm guessing not, since your code already uses them.  Ok, I don't have a clue what you are asking for either.

Comment: the user will save an excel file to any location of their computer they will name the file and then save it, then my open button will find the location of that file once they click the open file button. . and yes to save the file I am using the saveFileDialog. is it possible to my program to find the location of the file the user created?

Comment: When you save the file, you can save the location of it in one of your variables. In simple terms, make your `sd` variable an instance variable (with a proper name). Then you can refer to this in your `OpenFile` method.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create a variable to save the file path when the user saved. You can do so by using:

```
    String filepath; //global variable

    Stream stream;
    SaveFileDialog sf = new SaveFileDialog();
    if(sf.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
            if((stream = sf.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                    filepath = sf.FileName; 
                    //Do save work
            }
    }
```

Comment: Hello Joe, I was able to manage to add your code, but I am getting an error for the if(sf.ShowDialog() == true) is the error comes from the ==, also how will I refer the global variable filePath to the openfile button, I tried to added but is giving me an error.       
 // Open a File
            xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open(filepath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

Comment: Sorry it might have been my mistake as I didn't look at your code before I type this. Since you already have sf.ShowDialog(), you don't need the if() statement but all you really need is the **sf.FileName** part. I see that you were already using it, which is great. Now the last step is to create the global variable, maybe in the class that contains both methods. Just to clarify that global variable should be declared outside the SaveFile function, so that OpenFile can access it too.

Comment: I added the global variable filePath, but now is giving an error after I close my application and select the ope file button this error The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE),  the error comes from the open file button             // Open a File
            xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open(file, 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);